Specialized Ruby 2012 replacement Front Crank/Chainring/Hub
I would like to convert SRAM Power Spline with 50/34 POWERGLIDE chainrings to a 50/30 T combo.  It has 110mm so will not accept 30T.
What crank assembly/bottom bracket and chainrings should I use to replace the current crankshaft with?
This is a Specialized Ruby 2012.

If you are happy to increase your cadence on the higher gears, then maybe this 46/30 will do.  This setup works with a 110mm BCD but it has it's own proprietary design to overcome what would normally be incompatible between 30 and 110mm. https://www.amazon.ca/bikinGreen-Chainring-110mm-Bolts-Silver/dp/B097ZKVJZW
Also look at the comments on it, sixth commend from post: https://www.bikeforums.net/general-cycling-discussion/1226924-absoluteblack-bikingreen-chainrings.html

Sorry that was meant to be the ninth 9# comment on bikeforums
